# What's the name of this surface: $z = \exp(xy)$ [exponentialoid?]

Tags: terminology, curves-and-surfaces

When studying the real value exponential, I encounter the surface $z = e^{x\cdot y}$ but I don't know if it has a name. I've created [a 3D applet](https://www.geogebra.org/m/neecnddv) to explore it. When I cut it by the plane
$$
(x-x_0)\cos(α) + (y-y_0)\sin(α) = 0 
$$
which is defined by two parameters, a point $P(x_0,y_0,0)$ and an angle $\alpha$, I get a family of curves:

- When $\alpha = k\pi/4$: exponential growth/decay $z(t) = e^{\lambda t}$.
- When $2k\pi/4 < \alpha < (2k+1)\pi/4$: Gaussian function $z(t) = a\exp\left(-\frac{(t-b)^2}{2c^2}\right)$.
- When $(2k+1)\pi/4 < \alpha < (2k+2)\pi/4$: exponential of squared $z(t) = a\exp\left(\frac{(t-b)^2}{2c^2}\right)$.

Comment: I would suggest $z=e^{xy}$ suffices as a name.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, but not aware of any name.

Since log of z is a Hypar we may pehaps call it exponential or "deep" Hypar. short for hyperbolic paraboloid.

A suggestion: The Monge surface $ z=f(x,y)$ form has regions of positive and negative Gauss curvature exactly demarcated/ separated by  vertical planes making asymptotic line boundary intersections from two  planes odes given by

$$ r\; dx^2+ 2 s  \;dx dy + t \: dy^2=0\;$$

If $ p= \dfrac{dy}{dx},$ odes in xy plane are in qudratic equation

$$ p^2 (x+x^2)+2p (1+xy)+(y+y^2)=0$$

$$ Q=\frac{1+xy}{x+x^2}; \quad p=Q\pm\sqrt{Q^2-\frac{y(1+y)}{x(1+x)}}.\;$$

It may be of interest to include them in the applet showing by thick lines in the Top View.